# Application.xml vs sun-application.xml

Tags: java, configuration, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm developing a JSF2 application using Glassfish which contains some EJB's; is there a reason I should use sun-application.xml versus the standard application.xml file?

I would like to deploy my application as an exploded EAR.  Do I need to do anything special with the application xml configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use application.xml for standard j2ee configuration, sun-application.xml is the vendor specific descriptor.  You'll find that other containers have vendor specific descriptors -- like jboss-application.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, are the vendor-specific descriptors optional (unless I want vendor-specific things)?

Comment: It seems standard application.xml is optional and sun-application.xml is enough if one is deploying to glassfish (v2.1.1) only.